# How to style RatingBar inside ListView? (Problems in API 21 and low)

Tags: android, listview, ratingbar

I have a RatingBar inside a Relative Layout:

All Ok, grey and golden stars. https://www.dropbox.com/s/22y8117fwyv969x/Stars23.JPG?dl=0

But if I have the same RatingBar inside a ListView the result is:

- API 23: All Ok, grey and golden stars (the same)
- API 21: Rating is set to 5 and all stars are golden
- API 19: Rating is set to 5 and all stars are black https://www.dropbox.com/s/waotjqof17mt3ag/Stars19.JPG?dl=0

What is the problem? How can I solve it? Any ideas?

Code:

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratings_list_item_ratingBar"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small"
    android:theme="@style/RatingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:isIndicator="true"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="1"/>
```

Style in styles.xml:

```
<style name="RatingBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/Yelow200</item>
</style>
```

Adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater
                            .inflate(R.layout.ratings_list_item, parent, false);
            RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ratings_list_item_ratingBar);
            float ratingNumber = (float)values.get(position).getRating();
            ratingBar.setRating(ratingNumber);
            return rowView;
    }
```

Comment: is your project has other style-v19 and style-v21 ?

Comment: If you're using a ListView, do you have an Adapter implementing a getView() method? If so, please share the code

Comment: @0X0nosugar Updated with the adapter but i don't change style on adapter

Comment: @DivyeshPatel RatingBar style is in styles.xml. style-v19 and style-v21 have not RatingBar style

Comment: then add there too. maybe they are taking default color for rating bar

Comment: Thanks @DivyeshPatel I've tried but the same, no changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LayoutInflater` you are using may not be taking notice of your application's style.xml.

Try (sorry, no way of testing this before, but it helped in a similar case) using the following LayoutInflater:

`LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());`